# how to achieve Circular page animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, animation

I am trying to create this [animation effect shown in this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCxWY.gif) where the population page animates to the left and diet page comes up in flutter (the circular effect). But not able to get my head around how can i achieve this in flutter. Any suggestions on how to achieve this? I was checking animateTo() func on page controller in page view but not of much help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using pageview builder and transform widgets with some customization. see the result [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jDLeG-7siMp3BAuf7bAWjAU3HJWUwkJ_/view?usp=sharing)